# Cannot call my custom admin controller in prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.5

I found `AdminController::getController();` to call instance controller.
i created my controller : `class SolrBrigdeGetProductController extends AdminController{}`
I called `$a = AdminController::getController('SolrBrigdeGetProductController');
        $a->example('toanloau');`
but i get error: `Fatal error: Class 'SolrbrigdeSearchController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop_test\classes\controller\Controller.php on line 128`
file  SolrBrigdeGetProductController.php in prestashop/modules/bridge/controllers/admin folder

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the SolrBrigdeGetProduct object, Like this

```
    $a = new SolrBrigdeGetProduct();
```